# Combining different groups on ordered condition in dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping, dplyr

Sorry for the confusing title.  Suppose I have a sample dataset defined by:

```
date_seq = seq(as.Date("2010/1/1"), as.Date("2015/1/1"), "years")
testdf = data.frame( date = rep(date_seq, 3), 
            group= c(rep(1, length(date_seq)), rep(2, length(date_seq)), rep(3, length(date_seq)) ),
            value = runif( 3*length(date_seq) ) )
```

The df would look like:

```
        date group      value
1  2010-01-01     1 0.87025714
2  2011-01-01     1 0.11047751
3  2012-01-01     1 0.72883205
4  2013-01-01     1 0.74132252
5  2014-01-01     1 0.55877268
6  2015-01-01     1 0.98447795
7  2010-01-01     2 0.22791086
8  2011-01-01     2 0.71533778
9  2012-01-01     2 0.71589941
10 2013-01-01     2 0.72400212
11 2014-01-01     2 0.81055940
12 2015-01-01     2 0.68812890
13 2010-01-01     3 0.60479478
14 2011-01-01     3 0.64756971
15 2012-01-01     3 0.86421177
16 2013-01-01     3 0.99849809
17 2014-01-01     3 0.96150739
18 2015-01-01     3 0.05425983
```

What's the easiest way to divide the values of group 3 by the values of group 1?  I know I can merge the the data with itself on the date and then divide, but that's a bit clumsy.  dplyr functions are welcome.

Edit: I provided a pretty well-mannered dataset.  It would also be nice if the answer was robust enough to handle missing dates (e.g. if the 2011-01-01 point for group 1 was missing), and if the dates were not ordered.

Comment: `testdf[testdf$group==3,"value"]/testdf[testdf$group==1,"value"]`? If NA, it returns NA.

Comment: Use spread to put groups in columns?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following (It can probably be done in less steps but I 'd rather show it in detail below):

```
#split into groups
df2 <- split(testdf, as.factor(testdf$group))

#order each group according to date
df2[] <- lapply(df2, function(x) x[order(x$date),])

#cbind the two groups to remove NAs using na.omit
df3 <- cbind(df2[[1]], df2[[3]])
df3 <- na.omit(df3)

#divide the values to produce final output
df4 <- cbind(df3[1], df3[3]/df3[6])
```

Output:

```
> df4
        date      value
1 2010-01-01 0.04760063
2 2011-01-01 0.10221574
3 2012-01-01 0.61679424
4 2013-01-01 0.02227756
5 2014-01-01 0.28233571
6 2015-01-01 1.49104843
```